# Size of the collection of morphisms of a category

Tags: category-theory

Suppose we use Grothendieck'universes, at least 2 (named U and W).

U has elements called (small-) Sets and its subcollections are called Classes.

W has elements called Classes and its subcollections are called Conglomerates.

This follows "the joy of cats" terminology.

Now the question: if I have a collection of Classes $U_j$, indexed by a Class $I$ ($j \in I$), is the union of all these Classes $$\bigcup_{j\in I}U_j$$
a Class itself?

I think so, since we can apply axiom 4 in the definition of [universe W](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grothendieck_universe).

Is this correct? If yes than we could say that a category whose objects a,b,... form a Class $Ob$ and whose $Hom(a,b)$ form Classes, has a collection of morphisms $Mor$ which is also a Class. Am I right?

Comment: You've given "Classes" two different definitions, namely (1) subcollections of $U$ and (2) elements of $W$. If (as you presumably intended) $W$ is a larger Grothendieck universe than $U$, then there are far more Classes in sense (2) than in sense (1).

Comment: @AndreasBlass this is an excellent observation! It appears that I am identifying W with the powerset of U. Is this not correct? Then what would be the proper definition of W? I want W to be the smallest universe properly containing U. I also want to maintain the definition of Class as a subcollection of U. Put it in another way: what would be an appropriate name for the elements of W and the subcolections of W?

Comment: In order to be a Grothendieck universe with $U$ as an element, $W$ must not only contain the power set of $U$, but also the power set of that, and so forth, iterated for a very large transfinite number of steps (larger than the cardinality of $U$ or of its power set or of any other element of $W$).  Unfortunately, I'm not aware of any standard name for the elements of a larger universe $W$, after one has already used "small set" for the elements of $U$.